# How to give curved edges for a popup window and a noticeable shadow to the popup window

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

I have to give curved edges to a popup window with a noticeable shadow to the popup window is working fine but without the curved edges and a noticeable shadow the background window and the popup window doesn't show a noticeable space in b/w them

```
    DisplayMetrics dm=new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width=dm.widthPixels;
    int height=dm.heightPixels;
    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*1.0),(int)(height*.8));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        getWindow().setElevation(40);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very simple, try this:-

First create a custom popup and assign a custom layout to it.

```
private fun channelPopup(){

        //   addDummyProfile()
        channelDialog = Dialog(context)
        channelDialog!!.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        val lp = channelDialog!!.getWindow()!!.getAttributes()
        val window = channelDialog!!.getWindow()
        window!!.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
        channelDialog!!.getWindow()!!.setAttributes(lp)
        channelDialog!!.getWindow()!!.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)
        channelDialog!!.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
        channelDialog!!.setCancelable(true)
        channelDialog!!.setContentView(R.layout.exitsing_channel_layout)
        val tv_videos_no: TextView = channelDialog!!.findViewById(R.id.tv_videos_no) as TextView
        val recycler_channel = channelDialog!!.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_channel)
        recycler_channel!!.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(context)
        channelAdapter = ChannelAdapter(tv_videos_no)
        recycler_channel!!.adapter = channelAdapter
        channelDialog!!.show()
    }
```

and then in your layout give the parent layout a custom background,create a new drawable xml and paste this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="30dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

and then set this drawable XML as background to the parent layout of custom popup layout XML.

Add this line in custom popup Java file.

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: This code is only giving the background a curved shape but the edges of the popup window is still square.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot one line.please check the edited answer

Comment: To remove the edges of the popup window, set background drawable of popup window as null. Give background color to your custom layout instead.